# How to solve Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (VisitingCount int, [Time] int, [Date] nvarchar(50) )
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int,@Time int, @Date nvarchar(50)
set @DateNow='00:00'  
set @i=1;  
while(@i^60;48)  
    begin  
        set @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
        set @Time = (datepart(hour,@DateNow)*60+datepart(minute,@DateNow))/30 
        set @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@DateNow, 108)
        insert into #Temp(VisitingCount,[Time],[Date]) values(0,@Time,@Date )
        set @i=@i+1
    end
```

```
select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time],Date
from (
  select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time],Date
    from #Temp group by [Time],Date
  Union All
    select count(page) as VisitingCount,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108), 
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between '2009-05-12' and '2009-05-13'
    GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)
  ) X
group by [Time],Date
order by 2 asc
```

#### Error

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00:30' to data type int.

#### ERROR AREA:   select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time],Date.................

Comment: This is precisely the problem you'll get into when the designer of the database picks the wrong data type for the columns. The correct way to handle this is to fix the data, and possibly the data type. A less optimal way would be to write a sql-server function that converts, and checks for common problems, or uses TRY/CATCH to avoid a hard crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second part of your union the data types used are (int, date, time) whereas in the first part they are (int, time, date).  Try changing the order of the columns in either the first or the second part of the union.